# How do I use Project Oxford's Speech API to implement solution into a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, azure-cognitive-services

I have been unable to find relevant documentation whose link has not been broken.

I want to implement all the API features of Project Oxford's Speech API into my WPF application. The features include adding, editing and deleting of Intent, Entities, Prebuilt Entities, Phrase Lists.

So how do I bring all these controls into my WPF application and be able to use the Speech API in real time?

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Speech here you can see some examples.

Comment: Noted and thank you. I still need to find out the functions that are available in the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just renamed Project Oxford to Microsoft Cognitive Services; I wonder if that broke some links.  (Apologies if so!)  All of the APIs are listed at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/apis.

The Speech API specifically is at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api.  I clicked through on that and found detailed documentation on individual classes at https://staging.www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/Windows/html/2f2b6f71-0a81-b331-fe50-dc681063bbf8.htm.  Does that help?

Comment: Awesome! I think I found everything that I need to proceed. Thank you very much.